# Regex error in Netbeans not present in other editors

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, netbeans

I have the following regular expression that works fine in my application code and other code editors have not reported a problem with it. It is used to validate a password.

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])+(?=.*[\d])+(?=.*[^A-Za-z\d\s])+.*$/
```

So in other words:

Must have one letter
Must have one digit
Must have one non-letter, non-digit

Now it seems netbeans has a fairly decent regex parser and it has reported that this is an erroneous statement. But as i am new to regex I cannot spot the error. Is it due to using the positive lookahead `?=` with the one or more `+` at the end?

When I take out the `+` the error goes away, but the regex stops performing in my application.

If anyone can tell me what is wrong with my expression that would be great.

The statement is used in a jQuery validation plugin that i use, if that helps. Also due to the fact I am using a plugin, I would prefer not splitting this into several smaller (clearly simpler and cleaner) expressions. That would require a great deal of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never makes sense to apply a quantifier to a zero-width assertion such as a lookahead.  The whole point of such assertions is that they allow you to assert that some condition is true, without consuming any of the text--that is, advancing the current match position.  Some regex flavors treat that as a syntax error, while others effectively ignore the quantifier.  Getting rid of those plus signs makes your regex correct:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z\d\s]).*$/
```

If it doesn't work as expected, you may be running into [the infamous IE lookahead bug](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/regex-lookahead-bug).  The usual workaround is to reorder things so the first lookahead is anchored at the end, like so:

```
/^(?=.{8,15}$)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^A-Za-z\d\s]).*/
```

The `(?=.{8,15}$)` is just an example; I have no idea what your real requirements are.  If you do want to impose minimum and maximum length limits, this is the ideal place to do it.

Comment: That makes sense. I figured the quantifier was the issue. Thanks for the solution